# Can't get safari to load my assets asynchronously

Tags: javascript, three.js, safari

Hello I'm developing a game in JS with Three.js and I'm loading the 3D models asynchronously.

This is the loader:

```
import * as THREE from "./dependencies/three.module.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "./dependencies/GLTFLoader.js";

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

export async function loadAssets(){
    const [kitchenData, 
        burgerData,
        rapperData,
        skaterData,
        muppieData,
        gamerData,
        chefData] = await Promise.all([
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/kitchen.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/burger.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/rapper.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/skater.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/muppie.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/gamer.glb"),
            loader.loadAsync("../assets/chef.glb") 
        ]);

        const [kitchenModel,
            burgerModel,
            rapperModel,
            skaterModel,
            muppieModel,
            gamerModel,
            chefModel] = [
            kitchenData.scene,
            burgerData.scene,
            rapperData.scene,
            skaterData.scene,
            muppieData.scene,
            gamerData.scene,
            chefData.scene
            ];
        
        return{
            kitchenModel,
            burgerModel,
            rapperModel,
            skaterModel,
            muppieModel,
            gamerModel,
            chefModel
        }
}
```

and this is where I load it:

```
import * as THREE from "./dependencies/three.module.js";
import { loadAssets } from "./loader.js";
import gsap from "./dependencies/gsap/index.js";




const {kitchenModel, 
    burgerModel,
    rapperModel,
    skaterModel,
    muppieModel,
    gamerModel,
    chefModel} = await loadAssets();



var lastNumber;
var nextNumber;




function randomExcluded(lastNumber) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3-0) + 0);
    if (n >= lastNumber) n++;
    return n;
}

function nextModel(last){
    var arr;
    if(last === 0){
        arr = [1,2,3,4];
       
    }
    else if(last === 1){
        arr = [0,2,3,4];
    }
    else if(last === 2){
        arr = [0,1,3,4];
    }
    else if(last === 3){
        arr = [0,1,2,4];
    }
    else if(last === 4){
        arr = [0,1,2,3]
    }
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * (3-0) + 0)]
}
 
export const modelSwitcher = (delta) =>{
    var modelNumber = nextModel(lastNumber);
    console.log(lastNumber);
    console.log(modelNumber)
    switch(modelNumber){
        case 0:
            burger.animate(delta);
            console.log('burger');
            break;
        case 1:
            rapper.animate(delta);
            console.log('rapper');
            break;
        case 2:
            skater.animate(delta);
            console.log('skater');
            break;
        case 3:
            muppie.animate(delta);
            console.log('muppie');
            break;
        case 4: 
            gamer.animate(delta);
            console.log('gamer');
            break;
    }
}

class Burger{
    constructor(model,model_name,model_number){
        this.model_number = 0;
        this.model = burgerModel;
        this.model_name = 'burger';
        this.onCreate()
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
        this.model.position.set(1,0,-.6);
    }
    animate(delta){
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ease: "linear"});
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:1.1,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:2.2,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-1.5,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:-1.1,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>lastNumber=this.model_number)
        timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta)})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-3.2,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:-0.6,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:0,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = false})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:1.12,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:0,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = true})
    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Rapper{//2 parones previos a pasar
    constructor(model,model_name,model_number){
        this.model_number = 1;
        this.model = rapperModel;
        this.model_name = 'rapper';
        this.onCreate();
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
        this.model.position.set(1,0,-.6);
    }
    animate(delta){
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ease: "linear"});
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:1.1,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:2.2,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-1.5,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:-1.1,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>lastNumber=this.model_number)
        timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta)})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-3.2,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:-0.6,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:0,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = false})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:1.12,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:0,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = true})
    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Skater{//acelera exponencialmente
    constructor(model,model_name,model_number){
        this.model_number = 2;
        this.model = skaterModel;
        this.model_name = 'skater';
        this.onCreate();
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
        this.model.position.set(1,0,-.6);  
    }
    animate(delta){
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ease: "linear"});
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:1.1,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:2.2,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-1.5,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>lastNumber=this.model_number)
        timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta)})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:-1.1,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-3.2,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:-0.6,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:0,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = false})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:1.12,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:0,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = true})
        //timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta,this.model_number)})
    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Muppie{//hace parón y sigue
    constructor(model,model_name,model_number){
        this.model_number = 3;
        this.model = muppieModel;
        this.model_name = 'muppie';
        this.onCreate();
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
        this.model.position.set(1,0,-.6);
    }
    animate(delta){
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ease: "linear"});
        timeline.add(()=>lastNumber=this.model_number)
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:1.1,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:2.2,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-1.5,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:-1.1,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-3.2,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:-0.6,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:0,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = false})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:1.12,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:0,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = true})
        timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta)})
    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Gamer{
    constructor(model,model_name,model_number){
        this.model_number = 4;
        this.model = gamerModel;
        this.model_name = 'gamer';
        this.onCreate();
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
        this.model.position.set(1,0,-.6);
    }
    animate(delta){//hace parón, vuelve y sigue
        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ease: "linear"});
        timeline.add(()=>lastNumber=this.model_number)
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:1.1,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:2.2,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-1.5,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:-1.1,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:-3.2,duration:.1+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{z:-0.6,duration:.8+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{y:0,duration:.3+delta,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = false})
        timeline.to(this.model.position,{x:1.12,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.to(this.model.rotation,{y:0,duration:.1,ease:'linear'})
        timeline.add(()=>{this.model.visible = true})
        timeline.add(()=>{modelSwitcher(delta)})
    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Kitchen{
    constructor(model,model_name){
        this.model = kitchenModel;
        this.model_name = 'kitchen';
        this.onCreate()
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(3,3,3); 
    }
    animate(){

    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

class Chef{
    constructor(model,model_name){
        this.model = chefModel;
        this.model_name = 'kitchen';
        this.onCreate()
    }
    onCreate(){
        this.model.name = this.model_name;
        this.model.scale.set(1,1,1);
        this.model.position.set(-.5,0,0)
    }
    animate(){

    }
    add(scene){
        scene.add(this.model)
    }
}

export const burger = new Burger();
export const rapper = new Rapper();
export const skater = new Skater();
export const muppie = new Muppie();
export const gamer = new Gamer();
export const kitchen = new Kitchen();
export const chef = new Chef();

export function addAssets(scene){
    kitchen.add(scene);
    chef.add(scene);
    burger.add(scene);
    rapper.add(scene);
    skater.add(scene);
    muppie.add(scene);
    gamer.add(scene);
}

export function setIronHitbox(){
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( .7, .5, .5 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(0,1,2.35);
    mesh.scale.set(.7,1,1)
    return mesh;
}
```

For some reason (Safari is the new IE), Im getting ```"SyntaxError:unexpected identifier 'loadAssets'. Expected ';' after variable declaration"´´´

I don't get what's wrong, It works on every single browser except Safari (iOS/MacOs).

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Try declaring the loadAssets function like a normal function, and then do `export loadAssets`

Comment: doesn't work :/